# No wireless option on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with new laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, dual-boot, wireless

. Hi, so I'm quite new to Linux, I use dual-boot with windows 11 and I can't find a way to make the wifi option show up.

Nothing that I found with googling was useful so I guess my only option now is to make my own post.

I have a MSI Creator Z16P with the following network controller : Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi Wifi.

Bluetooth is working fine, I tried updating drivers but that didn't work and honestly I can't remember all the things I tried but I suspect that ubuntu do not recognize the wifi adapter or something.

The "rfkill list" command only show bluetooth.

The "sudo lshw -C network" command show this :

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:620-61f memory:622d194000-622d197fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 14
       bus info: usb@2:1.2.1
       logical name: enxa0cec86264dd
       serial: a0:ce:c8:62:64:dd
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ax88179_178a driverversion=5.15.0-25-generic duplex=half link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 15
       logical name: bnep0
       serial: 4c:03:4f:ba:13:4f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes ip=172.20.10.6 multicast=yes
```

(is it possible that it shouldn't be "UNCLAIMED" ? If so, how can I fix this)

I'm not sure what informations would be useful here and how to get them so if there's anything I can do I'd appreciate some help regarding this :)

Edit : the following message shows at startup > "iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 51f0/1672, rev=0x370, rfid=0x2010d000"

Comment: @David I mistyped 22.04, I'll see if I can edit the title.

Comment: Certainly not recognized as a working wireless  -- my capabilities are: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless  . Have you checked for the latest firmware update from the vendor?  Try an alpha/beta release kernel, the latest one you can get working might help too.

Comment: 8086:51f0 is not covered until kernel version 5.17. Please follow the duplicate. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Finally, thank you very much @chili555 for your quick answer. Installed 5.17 oem version and I now have access to wifi.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. Duplicate questions are closed and may be removed by the system admin. Please see the [site's help center](https://askubuntu.com/help) for better understanding how how this site works.